# How to make Behat look for occurences of a specific text?

Tags: php, behat, gherkin

I'd like to create a function that makes Behat parse my HTML and tell me how many times he finds a specific text. I found countless ways to do so, but since I'd like to reuse the concept, I can't give him a specific div class where to find it since it could be outside of a div.

This is what I did so far

**testfeature.feature**

```
And I should see "CISIA - Arcueil" 2 times
```

**FeatureContext.php**

```
public function iShouldSeeTimes($text, $count) {

  $element = $this->getSession()->getPage();
  $result = $element->findAll('css',  sprintf('div:contains("%s")', $text));

  if(count($result) == $count && strpos(reset($result)->getText(), $text)) {
    return;
  }

  else {
    throw  new ExpectationException('"' . $text . '" was supposed to appear ' . $count . ' times, got ' . count($result) . ' instead', $this->getSession());
  }
}
```

This is a bit messy but I'll tidy all of this up once it works. So far, with this code, I get 19 elements, which are every text contained by every div inside the page I want to check. In a way, I have a possibility to get to my goal, but what I'd like is to directly get what I need (my two occurences) inside `$result`. However, it looks like I'm doing something wrong with the `sprintf()` function.

Is there a way to make Behat look for a specific text?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `XPath` that matches any type of element with contains instead of `css`.

For example:

```
$text = 'my text';
findAll('xpath', "//*[contains(text(), '$text')]");
```

The second alternative would be to use regular expressions. I recommend the first one.

Comment: Or you can use `findAll('xpath', "//*[contains(., '$text')]");` which gives you more results!